# SwiftUI Custom Shape doesn't work correctly

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a custom separator as a `Shape`. I also have a view on which I put my separator (I add it 3 times and separated by spacers).
Below I added a capsule with spacing 4. According to the idea my custom separator and capsule should have the same spacings.

Why doesn’t it work like that?

// Separator struct

```
struct ProgressBarSeparator: View{

    struct RightShape: Shape {
        func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
            let offsetX = rect.maxX - rect.width / 4
            let crect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 4, height: 4)).offsetBy(dx: offsetX, dy: .zero)

            var path = Rectangle().path(in: rect)
            path.addPath(Circle().path(in: crect))

            return path
        }
    }

    struct LeftShape: Shape {
        func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
            let offsetX = rect.minX - rect.width / 4
            let crect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 4, height: 4)).offsetBy(dx: offsetX, dy: .zero)

            var path = Rectangle().path(in: rect)
            path.addPath(Circle().path(in: crect))

            return path
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 8, height: 4)
            .foregroundColor(.gray)
            .mask(RightShape().fill(style: .init(eoFill: true)))
            .mask(LeftShape().fill(style: .init(eoFill: true)))
    }
}
```

// Progress bar view

```
private var progressBar: some View {
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Capsule()
                .foregroundColor(ColorName.black400.color)
                .frame(height: 4)

            Capsule()
                .fill(gradient)
                .frame(width: (proxy.size.width - 12) * 0 / 4, height: 4)
                .animation(.easeInOut)

            HStack.zeroSpacing {
                Spacer()
                ProgressBarSeparator()
                Spacer()
                ProgressBarSeparator()
                Spacer()
                ProgressBarSeparator()
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

// Example capsule

```
private var procentCashback: some View {
    HStack(spacing: 4) {
        ForEach(0 ... 3) { index in
            ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Capsule()
                    .fill(.orange)
                    .frame(height: 4)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[My broken view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzF1l.png)

Comment: I couldn't quite understand what you're trying to achieve, could you elaborate please? If you have a picture of the desired result, that will help. Or perhaps you might annotate your screenshot to highlight the layout that doesn't behave as you expected.

Comment: @VadimBelyaev Vadim, 
I have 2 views (progressBar and procentCashback), at the first view in Z stack, I added 3 separators (ProgressBarSeparator) and stretched them proportionally (Spacer) to the width of the view (on the image 1 view). 
Below I added another view, and added spacing to it.
If you look at the image, you can see that the first view differs in separators from the second view (they are the same in the center, and shifted on the sides). What could be the problem?

Comment: You explicitly set the width of `ProgressBarSeparator` to 8 points while in `procentCashback` the `HStack`'s spacing is 4 points.